# Binding Multiple Events With Blur

Tags: jquery, blur

I have the following code:

```
<script>

$('#changequantity').on('blur',function() { 


$("#manyquantity1").val($("#changequantity").val());

$("#manyquantity2").val($("#changequantity").val());

$("#manyquantity3").val($("#changequantity").val());

$("#manyquantity4").val($("#changequantity").val());

$("#manyquantity5").val($("#changequantity").val());

$("#manyquantity6").val($("#changequantity").val());

$("#manyquantity7").val($("#changequantity").val());
)
};


</script>
```

What I want to happen, is that when the value of changequantity is changed, that all of the other textboxes change also.

It doesn't seem to have any effect at all at present.

Comment: Check your console for errors as that should work.  Can you give us a link or a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#changequantity').on('change',function() { 
        $('[id^="manyquantity"]').val(this.value);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NqFmK/1/)

Comment: @Archer - as usual someone didn't undertand the answer and decided to downvote.